# What could be the cause of AWS Canary showing 10s Blocking when loading a page?

Tags: amazon-web-services, puppeteer, har

There is a 10s blocking that appears when the page.goto is called for an AWS Canary using NodeJS and Puppeteer. Below is the HAR portion of the page request:

[image]

Anyone have any suggestion on why it is blocking?

Other information:
I've added ignoreHTTPSErrors as the only additional configuration for the heartbeat check.

Doing this on a fresh nginx doesn't cause the blocking though so I'm not sure why there is a huge blocking delay.

[image]